# Efficient HashMap traversing

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap

I was doing my dev work and wondered which one of these could be better option in terms of code practice , memory and time efficiency ?

```
public static void printtHashmap(Map<?,?> hm)   {
    for(Object key : hm.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println(key+" "+hm.get(key));
    }
}

public static void printHashMapByEntry(Map<?,?> hm) {
    for(Map.Entry<?,?> entry: hm.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following is better

```
public static void printHashMapByEntry(Map<?,?> hm) {
    for(Map.Entry<?,?> entry: hm.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

because in other case for each key you have to lookup again in entire map for the corresponding value.

Comment: This is more like bookmarking the key and its value in the map.